# Using error raising to control if/else statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, error-handling

Learning ruby here, how can I use if an error was raised to control an if/else statement. In ruby pseudocode it would be something like.

```
if block.call raise? 
   #if block doesn't exist and an error is raised do this
else 
  #if block does exist do this
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same if you just used `begin ... rescue ... end` syntax? See http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html

Comment: `if`/`else` are the wrong tools for dealing with code which raises exceptions. You should be using `rescue`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inline rescue like this:

```
if block.call rescue false
else 
end
```

Though you shouldn't do this. The reason being that this will rescue *any error* in the block. Say you you mispelled some word in the block definition. Your code will act like this is intended, and you might have a hard time tracking it down.

In this case, to check if the block was given you can simply say `if block`. If you're using `yield` instead of the `&block` parameter, you can use the special method `if block_given?`.

Of course you can achieve conditional logic using rescues, but that's not what they're intended for, and it's not making things much simpler in most cases.